# Waiting till inner promises are done

Tags: typescript, promise

I want to wait that two or more Promises will be blocked, as long there results will be for me avaible.

Therefore I am using the `Promise.allSettled` method. This is working if the two Promises are flat. But if one of that Promises consists of inner Promises then it won't work.

```
 Promise.allSettled([
  report?.getActivePage(), //return a Promise object
  exportVisualData("9df20366a984c945beb5")
 ])
  .then((results) => {
    results.forEach((result, index) => {
      if (result.status === "rejected") {
        const rejectedResult: PromiseRejectedResult =
          result as PromiseRejectedResult;
        console.log(rejectedResult);
      } else if (result.status === "fulfilled") {
        if (index === 0) {
          const fulfilledResult: PromiseFulfilledResult<Page | undefined> =
            result as PromiseFulfilledResult<Page | undefined>;
          console.log(fulfilledResult);
          fulfilledResult.value?.setActive();
        } else {
          const fulfilledResult: PromiseFulfilledResult<void | IExportDataResult> =
            result as PromiseFulfilledResult<void | IExportDataResult>;
          console.log(fulfilledResult);
        }
      }
   });

function exportVisualData(id: string): Promise<void | IExportDataResult> {
return report!.getPages().then((pages) => {
  pages.forEach((page) => {
    page.getVisuals().then((visualDescriptors) =>
      visualDescriptors.forEach((visualDescriptor) => {
        if (visualDescriptor.name === id) {
          if (!page.isActive) {
            page.setActive().then((__) => {
              return visualDescriptor?.exportData(
                ExportDataType.Summarized
              );
            });
          } else {
            return visualDescriptor?.exportData(ExportDataType.Summarized);
          }
        }
      })
    );
  });
});
```

Promise.allSettled hasn't have a result in the second due to the inner promises, how could I can get this to work.

{status: 'fulfilled', value: Page}
{status: 'fulfilled', value: undefined}

Comment: I do not follow your code, but inner promises can only be tracked by an outer/containing promise if you `return` them from the `.then()` handler so they become chained together.  And, you cannot do that properly from within a `.forEach()` loop either because returning anything from within a `.forEach()` loop doesn't go anywhere.  You would probably need to change to a `for` loop instead.  And, if you need to track all the promises in a loop, then use `Promise.all()` or `Promise.allSettled()` there.

Comment: @jfriend00 could you please write an example with pseudo code, I think I can't follow you to 100 percent

Comment: I was trying to rewrite your `exportVisualData()` function, but I can't tell what you mean to do when you do `return visualDescriptor?.exportData(ExportDataType.Summarized);`.  What are you trying to return that to?  You're inside a loop so are you trying to exit the loop when you get to that statement or are you trying to accumulate the results from each iteration of the loop?  I'm confused what this code is supposed to do.  Where is that return value supposed to go?  Where are N of them supposed to go?

Comment: ```visualDescriptor?.exportData(ExportDataType.Summarized)``` is an method from the Power BI API (https://playground.powerbi.com/de-de/dev-sandbox). My goal is currently to export the data for just one example visual. At the end, I want to collect the data from different visual objects inside one function call, as  an part of an array. Therefore I must change the input from a string to an array of string.

Comment: Let me ask a different way.  What do you want the resolved value to be of the promise that `exportVisualData()` returns?  You have two nested loops inside that function so you could be collecting an array of array of data.  Is that what you want?  Or do you just want the first value you find and then abort both loops after you find a good value and just return one value.

Comment: I need the two loops, because without the outer "pages" loop I can't access the "visuals" objects. As a result I want something like this at the end IExportDataResult[]

Comment: Let's say  the first loop has 5 iterations in it and the inner loop has 3 iterations in it.  This would create 5 x 3 = 15 results.  What do you want to return when you have 15 results?  Do you want to return all 15 in a flat array?  Return only the first one you find?  Return an array of 5 items that each consist of a nested array of 3 items?

Comment: In your example with 5 iterations and three inner loops, I would expect 15 results in the extreme case. But this is unlikely, because I always want to filter if the inner loop (here the visual object) matches the passed IDs. I expect at most as many results as I pass elements to the function exportVisualData.
For instance exportVisualData("axjk", "wsjxki", "wsix", "sxol") => max. 4 return values

Comment: OK, so you want a flat array of results of however many match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rewritten `exportVisualData()` function that collects whatever results meet your `visualDescriptor.name` test into an array and makes that array the resolved value of the promise that `exportVisualData()` returns.

I didn't know if `visualDescriptor?.exportData(ExportDataType.Summarized)` returns a promise or not.  In case it does, I put an `await` in front of it.  If it just returns a value directly, you can remove that `await`.

Also, I don't know TypeScript so you will have to add type info to this code:

```
async function exportVisualData(id: string): Promise < void | IExportDataResult > {
    const results = [];
    const pages = await report!.getPages();
    for (let page of pages) {
        let visualDescriptors = await page.getVisuals();
        for (let visualDescriptor of visualDescriptors) {
            if (visualDescriptor.name === id) {
                if (!page.isActive) {
                    await page.setActive();
                }
                results.push(await visualDescriptor?.exportData(ExportDataType.Summarized));
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Note, this does not run all these asynchronous operations in parallel, so there is no need to use `Promise.allSettled()` on the result.  It just returns a single promise that resolves to an array of values.

If you want to catch errors and keep processing in this function, you can try/catch in each loop and `continue` in the `catch`.

If you wanted to run everything in parallel, that is more difficult to code here because of your `if (visualDescriptor.name === id)` that wants to skip some items so you don't know how many results you are waiting for until you're far into the results.